# Prevent the need to use Login-AzureRmVm before being able to stop the VM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Before I can the command Stop-AzureRmVM I need to use Login-AzureRmVm and enter my login credentials every time.

I want to prevent this.

Is there any way how I can prevent the need to login to use (most of) PowerShell commands in an Azure VM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to log in every time, but you can avoid the interactive login process by providing the credentials. I believe you don't want the popup for the login and want it to happen non-interactively and fully automated way. You can use below code:

```
    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “YourPass” -AsPlainText -Force
    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“YourUser”, $secpasswd) 
    Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $mycreds
```

You will need to log in using Org account instead of live id. Refer: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=331007&clcid=0x409

You can also have this 3 line script auto execute when the PowerShell starts.

Comment: @MGroen I am glad it helped! Please upvote and mark as answer by clicking the up arrow and click on the tick mark below the arrows beside my answer, if this response was useful. Let me know if you need more help on this.